# Fix broken /review-beta/ links

Tags: discussion, review, broken-link

Our review system is... no longer in beta. Yet I still find review links (mostly here on Meta) that use [`/review-beta/`](/review-beta/). If I didn't look at the URL for everything, I probably wouldn't notice that I have to remove the `-beta` from the URL, but even so it gets annoying after a while.

If any passing community moderator has the time to hack up a script, it would save a lot of people a small annoyance while browsing older posts.

This is an issue network-wide, especially in comments, so it would help if this was done for all "post bodies".

Comment: I don't think anything should be done. If it's in posts, edit it. Otherwise, we can't control ancient contents, especially in comments. Things change.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/revision/504899/639083/) is a simple SEDE query with all posts on this site containing `/review-beta/`:

```
SELECT id AS [Post Link], CreationDate
  FROM posts WHERE body LIKE '%/review-beta/%'
  ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

It returns only 116 hits, which should be doable by a couple of users.

As @nicael mentions, using the regular [search function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2A%2Freview-beta%2F%2A%22) works better. It is down to only 6 hits now, so it seems we're done.

Comment: Note that just removing `-beta` from the link is below the 6 character limit. That conveniently enforces users like me to further improve the post...

Comment: That *is* convenient... Maybe it was deliberate!

Comment: Thanks for the edits.

Comment: SEDE isn't necessary here, and also it gets more difficult to find the un-edited questions with this query, since it's updated once a week. A better way would be to search for [`url:"*/review-beta/*"`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*%2Freview-beta%2F*%22)

Comment: It looks like all of the edits have been suggested.  We just need about twenty or so approved.